# Как словить определенную ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Работаю с ботом телеграм,который парсит гугл-таблицы. Когда данных после парсинга нет, я получаю

```
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting  https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets//values/A1%3AN24majorDimension=COLUMNS&alt=json returned "Requested entity was not found.">
```

Вопрос в том, как словить эту ошибку?
Например, так:

```
try:
      ...
except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError:
      ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> нужно сделать так, чтобы заключить код в try/except, и когда он
> получит эту ошибку код выполнялся заново.

Для этого очень удобно использовать декоратор `retrying.retry`.
Функция в параметре `retry_on_exception` определяет нужно ли пытаться выполнить повтор для данного исключения:

```
import retrying

i = 1; # Глобальная переменная исключительно для демонстрации

@retrying.retry(
    stop_max_attempt_number=5,
    retry_on_exception=lambda ex: True, # Для любого исключения
    wait_exponential_multiplier=500,
    wait_exponential_max=8000)
def foo():
    global i;
    print(f'Try foo...{i}')
    i+=1
    if i < 3:
        raise Error('Any error')

    print('Success')


foo()
```

> ```
> Try foo...1
> Try foo...2
> Success
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, так и ловить:

```
try:
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
except HttpError as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Comment: ваш код выдает такую ошибку: NameError: name 'HttpError' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Таки импортируйте свой HttpError, я взял raise из вашего же кода)

Comment: нужно сделать так, чтобы заключить код в try/except, и когда он получит эту ошибку код выполнялся заново. Но мне бы просто понять - как словить эту ошибку